# How to extract a string that occurs X times in a list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have list similar in structure to the toy example below.

dpy(head(lst)):

```
list(GAME1 = structure(list(Class = structure(c(2L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 
3L), .Label = c("fighter", "paladin", "rouge", "sorcerer", "wizard"
), class = "factor"), Score = c(6, 7, 6, 7, 7)), class = "data.frame",     row.names = c(NA, 
-5L)), GAME2 = structure(list(Class = structure(c(2L, 4L, 1L, 
 3L), .Label = c("cleric", "fighter", "monk", "wizard"), class =  "factor"), 
Score = c(5, 5, 5, 5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -4L)))
```

How would I extract strings found in X number of data frames in the list of lists. E.g. If I wanted to know how many strings appeared twice in my list in the first column each data frame. My results would be 'fighter'.

Not only this but I would want a sum of the total score the fighters had in all games they were in.

so my results from this method would be:

```
  Class     |  Score
 fighter    |  11
```

And Preferably in a new data frame.

Note. my actual data is very large, and consists of a total of 10 lists. I need a method which allows me to change the number of lists used in the analysis i.e. find all common strings from column X in 7 lists or find all common strings from column X in 4 lists.

Many thanks, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(lst, .id = "game") %>% 
    group_by(Class) %>% 
    summarize(occurance = n(),
           total_score = sum(Score)) %>% 
    filter(occurance > 1)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  Class   occurance total_score
  <chr>       <int>       <dbl>
1 fighter         2          12
2 wizard          2          11
```